# MongoDB on Azure VM connection Error Network is unreachable

Tags: mongodb, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have a MongoDB installed on a Azure VM but I can't connect remotely. Everything is double checked including : port Inbound and outboung to Azure VM, Firewall , MongoDB config file. I also tried every solution I found online without success. I also checked the remote access to a different service of mine running on port 8091 to check the Azure side and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Looks like the mongoDB service did not read the correct cfg file!!